# Prioritize top X amount of records with two conditions in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question regarding prioritizing the selection of a top group of records. Currently, I am selecting the top 30 records from a subgroup. I'd like to prioritize which records out of that subgroup get picked based on another field, called 'PTIFlag_PhoneHome'. I've included my where statement below. Anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this?

`WHERE (((ShiftSales_DevListEdit.RecordID) 
In (Select Top 30 ShiftSales_DevListEdit.RecordID 
from ShiftSales_DevListEdit 
where DealerJoin.dealer_id=ShiftSales_DevListEdit.DealerCode
Order By (ShiftSales_DevListEdit.RecordID))));`

Comment: it might be helpful to show us an example of what your data looks like and what you'd like it to look like.

Comment: Is the answer just as easy as inserting another OrderBy  :  PTIFlag_PhoneHome,   before RecordID ?

Comment: I did try to do that, unfortunately it gives me a 'Syntax error in query' message. The data I would like to prioritize on does not need to be included in the output, I would just like to prioritize records with the word "LAN" in that PTIFlag_PhoneHome field. So basically of the top 30 records for a record set, all fields with "LAN" would be taken first, and if any additional records were needed they would be taken from the rest of the set.